# overloading virtual function and calling derived function by pointer to base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Base {
  public:
  virtual int function() const {
    cout << "Base::function()\n";
    return 1;
  }
  virtual void function(string) const {}
};


class Derived : public Base {
  public:
       // overloading function() of base
       int function(int) const {
         cout << "Derived::function()\n";
         return 4;
    }
};


int main()
{
    string s("StackOverflow");
    Derived d;
    Base* b = &d;
    //calling derived::function() and function(s)    
    b->function();
    b->function(s);
}
```

Because of overloading, **name hiding** occour in derived class.
Because of keyword **virtual** at runtime Derived::function() should be called.

But the code compiles successfully.  link : http://ideone.com/fbVm0P
What is the reason for this strange behaviour?
**EDIT 1:**

```
d.function();  
d.function(s);
```

do not compile,as expected.

Comment: Tangent: Why are you including <bits/stdc++.h>?  That's not intended to be consumed by users, as it's an an internal implementation detail of G++.

Comment: You're calling through a base pointer, so the name-hiding is irrelevant.

Comment: You don't have a derived `function()` you only have a non-derived `function(int)`. Parameters make all the difference. Different parameters means different function.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: It's common in Unix-land, in order to get a bunch of standard library headers (all?).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I didn't know that.  I was about to complain that this presumably relies on undocumented behaviour that could change between releases, but it turns out the GCC docs do specify this.  So it's merely unportable!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: i had the notion that `Derived::int function() `should be called which is actually hidden from it. So code should give runtime error. During compiling, `C++` does type checking etc. on `Base::int` function() since it is actually inside Base. can you elaborate `You're calling through a base pointer, so the name-hiding is irrelevant.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overload resolution uses the static types (not that it would make a
difference here).  So both `b->function()` and `b->function( s )`
resolve to `Base::function`, with no error.  Finally, since these
functions have been declared `virtual`, the final resolution will take
into account any overloads in a derived class.  But there aren't any, so
the function in the base class will be called.

Name hiding occurs during name lookup, which is before overload
resolution, and also only concerns the static type; in an expression
like `b->function()` or `b->function( s )`, the compiler ignores
`Derived` completely; it does the name lookup on the static type.  Name
hiding would only come into consideration is the static type were
`Derived`; once the compiler found `function` in `Derived`, it would
look no further.

The global rules are fairly simple: name lookup (using static type),
then overload resolution (using static type), and finally, if the
resolved name is a virtual function, dynamic determination of the actual
function depending on the dynamic type.

Comment: "name hiding occurs during name lookup, which is before override resolution" could be more clear. It's true that compilation happens before running the program. But is that really what you're trying to say?

Comment: @Alf What I meant to say was that name lookup occurs before _overload_ resolution.  (Both of which are compile time.)  I've fixed it; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `int function() const` in the derived class.

Use the `override` keyword to avoid surprises like this, i.e.,

```
class Derived
    : public Base
{
public:
    // not overriding function() of base
    auto function(int) const
        -> int override // This won't compile, because it doesn't override.
    {
         cout << "Derived::function()\n";
         return 4;
    }
};
```

Comment: `There is no int function() const in the derived class.` This is why it should give runtime-error, but code runs perfectly. and i **don't want to oerride**. just doing it for learning purpose.

Comment: @aseem: please explain why you think a runtime error should result from not overriding a function.

Comment: During compiling, `C++` does type checking etc. on` Base::int function() ` since it is actually inside Base.During runtime,because of `virtual` compiler will look for `Derived::int function()` which is actually not visible due to name-hiding.

Comment: @aseem: The compiler is not present at runtime.  The function is `virtual`, which in practice it means it's called via a lookup through the object's [vptr/vtbl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).  That won't cause a runtime error.

Comment: Oh. Well first, name hiding and overriding do not affect each other (we say that they are "orthogonal" issues). Second, the way that virtual functions work is a bit different than your description. When you call a non-static member function `m` on an object via a pointer `p`, like `p->m()`, and `m` is virtual in the type that's known at compile time for the pointed at object, then the implementation of `m` called is *as if* a search for an `m` implementation had started in the *dynamic type* of the object pointed at by `p`, and proceeded up each base class chain, here finding `Base::function`.